# JQzoom - Zoom Picure not moveable after changing Image source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zooming, jqzoom

I'm using the JQuery to zoom images on my web site. I also created some Icons that will change the image to zoom if I click on it. Unfortunately after the Image change, the zoomed image is not moveable anymore. I can only see the top of the image in the zoom window. But when I move the mouse down, nothing happens. Does anyone know, what I did wrong?

Here is my source code for the java script function that is called by clicking on one of the icons:

```
function changePicture(imgSrc)
{    
document.getElementById("main-image-js").setAttribute("src", imgSrc);
document.getElementById("main-image-zoom").setAttribute("href", imgSrc);
$(".zoomWrapperImage").children('img').eq(0).attr("src", imgSrc);   
}
```

The Image to zoom is implemented like that:

```
<a class="main-image" href="Picture1.jpg" id="main-image-zoom" title="Zoom">
<img id="main-image-js" src="Picture1.jpg" width="380" style="display: inline; cursor: pointer;"></a>
```

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should clean the data from jQZoom before changing image source:

```
function changePicture(imgSrc)
{ 
    cleanJqzoom();

    $("#main-image-zoom").attr('href', imgSrc);
    $("#main-image-js").attr('src', imgSrc);

    initJqzoom();
}

function initJqzoom() { 
    $('.main-image').jqzoom(); 
}   

function cleanJqzoom() {
    // clean the data from jQZoom
    $('.main-image').removeData('jqzoom');
}
```